# _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser referenced from: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting below error when I try to compile my project in Xcode.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: `_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser` referenced from: …

I tried following but still the problem persists? Appreciate any help.

1. Removed "`NSObject+SBJSON.m`" and "`NSString+SBJSON.m`" files and added back to Compile sources of Build Phases.
2. Added i386 for Valid Architecures in Build Settings.
3. Tried with `-all_load` linker flag

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing your linker error so I'm not going to post this as an answer, but if you're tired of dealing with SBJsonParser you could switch to NSJSONSerialization (available as of Mac OS 10.7 and iOS 5.0).

Comment: NSJSONSerialization does not allow sax-style parsing like SBJson does... I imagine is what he is trying to do. If not,and your app is supporting iOS 5 and above, I would definitely recommend to use NSJSONSerialization as Aaron purposes.

Comment: Does your project contain `SBJsonParser.m`?  Does your target include that file?  Does `SBJsonParser.m` contain a line that says `@implementation SBJsonParser`?

Comment: Rob, yes SBJsonParser.m included in the target. SBJsonParser does contain @implementation SBJsonParser.

Comment: Just to be brutally thorough: SBJsonParser.m is included in the Compile Sources build phase of the target, correct?

Comment: @mharper: Nope, it's included only in the target

Comment: If SBJsonParser.m does *not* appear in the "Compile Sources" build phase of your target then I think @mharper hit on the solution---SBJsonParser isn't being compiled (even if the file's in your project) if SBJsonParser.m does not appear in the Compile Sources build phase.

Comment: What @AaronGolden said. Open up the Compile Sources build phase, click + and choose SBJsonParser.m and click "Add". See if that helps.

Comment: Tried without any luck.

Comment: Nuts. How about posting the build log?  Go to View --> Navigators --> Show Log Navigator.  Then click at on the topmost "Build xxx" entry in the log list on the left. Then select all the contents of the selected build log, copy, and paste into your question.  Should have a bunch of "Compile XXX.m" entries and the original error.

Comment: @mharper, please see the build log above in the question.

Comment: @codematrix, make sure you also add SBJsonWriter.m to the Compile Sources build phase, as well. Build again, then go to the build log, click on the entry that says "Compile SBJsonParser.m", copy it, and paste that ridiculously long 'CompileC' command in your question.

Comment: @mharper, Done. Please check above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30942/discussion-between-mharper-and-codematrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you add SBJsonWriter.m, SBJsonParser.m, and SBJsonBase.m into the Compile Sources build phase for your target.